# Unable to start mongdb after an upgrade in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-12.04

I've upgraded mongo from 2.4.2 to 2.6.10 version in the production server where I couldn't start the mongo service again.

Here is the log file:

```
2015-09-01T14:13:11.098+0000 [initandlisten] journal dir=/var/lib/mongodb/journal
2015-09-01T14:13:11.098+0000 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed


2015-09-01T14:13:11.098+0000 [initandlisten]
2015-09-01T14:13:11.098+0000 [initandlisten] ERROR: Insufficient free space for journal files
2015-09-01T14:13:11.098+0000 [initandlisten] Please make at least 3379MB available in /var/lib/mongodb/journal or use --smallfiles
2015-09-01T14:13:11.098+0000 [initandlisten]
2015-09-01T14:13:11.098+0000 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 15926 Insufficient free space for journals, terminating
2015-09-01T14:13:11.098+0000 [initandlisten] dbexit:
```

My journal files were empty and also i've set smallfiles=true in mongod.conf.Though nothing helped.

Edit: Here is the o/p of df-h

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      7.8G  4.8G  2.6G  65% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            3.7G   12K  3.7G   1% /dev
tmpfs           748M  336K  748M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            3.7G     0  3.7G   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/xvdb        30G   45M   28G   1% /mnt
```

Comment: Well, how much space is there in /var/lib/mongodb/journal?

Comment: Actually the folder is totally empty. Or should I look in any config files for this?

Comment: What matters is the space available on that filesystem. A directory does not have free space, the entire filesystem does. Update your answer with the output of `df -h`.

Answer (score 0):

Your / filesystem does not have enough space for the MongoDB journal files.

You should either resize it, or (even better) add another filesystem for the MongoDB databases.

Comment: Can you explain your answer please. Do you mean that there is not enough hard disk space?

Comment: @prit4fun Yes. (need more characters)

Answer (score 0):

Actually it wasn't the space issue, I've set smallfiles=true in older version of conf file. Setting them in a correct one did the job.